# XSL Sort the output of analyze-string

Tags: xslt-2.0

In the source XML I am given a string of key:value:extra sets. There is some inconsistency in the structure, so I use a regular expression to parse the string in to a sequence of xml, something like this:

```
 <Sets>
    <Set>
      <key/>
      <value/>
      <extra/>
    </Set>
    <Set>...
    <Set>...
 </Sets>
```

That part works fine, but I'd like to also sort `<Sets>`. Since `xsl:matching-substring` only gives me one match at a time, I'm struggling to understand how best to approach this. Is it possible to get the entire sequence of matches from `xsl:analyze-string` ? That might help.

An alternative idea would be to create a tree-fragment of each match, and then sort that. Any direction on how I might proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="unsorted">
 <Sets>
   <xsl:analyze-string select="..." regex="...">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
      <Set>
        <key><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/></key>
        <value>...</value>
        <extra>...</extra>
      </Set>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
 </Sets>
<xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="sorted">
  <xsl:perform-sort select="$unsorted/Sets/Set">
    <xsl:sort select="key"/>
  </xsl:perform-sort>
</xsl:variable>
```

Of course the contents of the xsl:matching-substring above is just meant as an example.

Comment: Martin this is fantastic. I was unaware there was a standalone sort method, very useful indeed.